# Unable to cast to List(Of point)

Tags: vb.net, list, ienumerable

I am passing in an array of PointF into my function to turn it into a `List(Of Point)`. I was getting an unable to cast from `TypedEnumerable` to `List(Of Point)`.

```
Public Shared Function ToListOfPoint(ByVal untypedCollection As IEnumerable) As List(Of Point)
    Return DirectCast(ToEnumerableOfPoint(untypedCollection), List(Of Point))
End Function

Public Shared Function ToEnumerableOfPoint(ByVal untypedCollection As IEnumerable) As IEnumerable(Of Point)
    If untypedCollection Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    ElseIf TypeOf untypedCollection Is IEnumerable(Of Point) Then
        Return DirectCast(untypedCollection, IEnumerable(Of Point))
    ElseIf TypeOf untypedCollection Is IEnumerable(Of PointF) Then
        For Each p As PointF In untypedCollection
            convertedList.Add(ToPoint(p))
        Next
        Return New TypedEnumerable(Of Point)(convertedList)
    Else
        Return New TypedEnumerable(Of Point)(untypedCollection)
    End If
End Function

<Serializable()> _
Public Class TypedEnumerable(Of T)
    Implements IEnumerable(Of T)

    Private wrappedEnumerable As IEnumerable

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Create a typed IEnumerable view
    ''' onto an untyped IEnumerable interface.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="wrappedEnumerable">IEnumerable interface to wrap.</param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal wrappedEnumerable As IEnumerable)
        MyBase.New()
        Me.wrappedEnumerable = wrappedEnumerable
    End Sub

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator(Of T) Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T).GetEnumerator
        Return New TypedEnumerator(Of T)(Me.wrappedEnumerable.GetEnumerator)
    End Function

    Public Function TypedEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator Implements System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return Me.wrappedEnumerable.GetEnumerator
    End Function

End Class
```

These top two functions are used to generated the class TypedEnumerable. I added this

```
        `ElseIf TypeOf untypedCollection Is IEnumerable(Of PointF) Then
        For Each p As PointF In untypedCollection
            convertedList.Add(ToPoint(p))
        Next
        Return New TypedEnumerable(Of Point)(convertedList)`
```

to make the exception to go away.

My next question is is there an easier way to an whole array of one type to an `IEnumerable` of another without going through each variable and casting it?

Comment: Try to invoke `.ToList()`

Comment: Which is it, an array of `PointF` or `Point`? Other than that, like Yacoub Massad said, use `.ToList()`

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot it is an Array of PointF and I returning an List(Of Point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast directly to a List. But you can create a new List by passing the IEnumerable in the constructor. Try:

```
Public Shared Function ToListOfPoint(ByVal untypedCollection As IEnumerable) As List(Of Point)
    Return New List(untypedCollection)
End Function
```